# Using 'Any' on IEnumerable<string> in OData LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, odata

I am using `Microsoft.Data.Odata` (5.6) to run following query:

```
IEnumerable<Service> services = context.Services.Expand(ServiceQueryExpansion)
    .Where(c =>
        (serviceNames.Any(s => s.Equals(
            c.ServiceName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))))
```

serviceNames is IEnumerable of string

I get following error while trying above query:

`Error translating Linq expression to URI: The source parameter for the 'Any' method has to be either a navigation or a collection property.`

How do I resolve this?

Comment: @RowlandShaw From OP *serviceNames is IEnumerable of string*

Comment: @RowlandShaw, I'm sorry, but the OP did in fact state that `serviceNames is IEnumerable of string`. Further, the OP stated that they wanted to use `Any` on that same type in the question.

Comment: `services` is `IEnumerable<Service>` (as we can see). `serviceNames` as the OP says he has declared outside of scope as `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: In Linq to OData as in Linq To SQL you can't use expressions that access complex local data.

Comment: Have you tried using serviceNames.Contains(c.ServiceName)?  I have used this successfully with string arrays in entity framework.

Comment: If you insert `.AsEnumerable().` just before the `.Where`, then the `Any` will be executed in .NET, not translated into SQL to be executed by the database server. That will work better. But beware that the database server will then have to fetch the entire collection of services and send them to .NET. That might be a performance problem depending on how many there are etc.

Comment: @Grax, .Contains throws following error:
{Error translating Linq expression to URI: The method 'Contains' is not supported.}

Comment: Can you make `serviceNames` a basic `string[]` instead? - Might also need to remove the StringComparison overload for `.Equals` too

Answer (score 3):

I know it is fun and exciting (sarcasm) but you can dynamically build your Where expression like this:

```
var serviceNames = new string[] { "SERVICE1","SERVICE2"};

Expression<Func<Service,bool>> inList = v => false;
var parameter = inList.Parameters[0];
var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter,"ServiceName");

foreach (var serviceName in serviceNames)
{
   var body = inList.Body;
   var constantExpression = Expression.Constant(serviceName);
   var equalityExpression = Expression.Equal(propertyExpression,constantExpression);

   body = Expression.OrElse(body,equalityExpression);

   inList = Expression.Lambda<Func<Service, bool>>(body, parameter);
}

IEnumerable<Service> services = context.Services.Expand(ServiceQueryExpansion)
    .Where(inList);
```

This method builds a custom where clause from your list which will resemble (v => v.ServiceName == "Service1" || v.ServiceName == "Service2" || v.ServiceName == "Service3")

You could probably follow the directions from my blog https://secureapplicationlifestyle.com/2013/07/filter-pattern-for-linq-query-filter.html to encapsulate this logic into a custom "WhereContains(yourListHere)" custom filter extension method.

Comment: Do note that the resulting expression grows with the collection. This will likely crash after a certain limit of items is reached (though possibly very high). Test this on a huge``serviceNames`` collection to make sure it works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
var services = context.Services.Expand(ServiceQueryExpansion).AsEnumerable()
      .Where(c => serviceNames.Contains(c.ServiceName));
```

But it will download entire Services collection.
Or:

```
var services = serviceNames.SelectMany(s=>
     context.Services.Expand(ServiceQueryExpansion).Where(c=> c.ServicaName == s));
```

That will create N requests.

I don't know any better way to do this in Linq to OData.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was apply the filter that I could, then to list and then make another filter once you have your results locally.

```
var services = context.Services.Expand(ServiceQueryExpansion).ToList();
services = services.Where(s => serviceNames.Any(n => n.ServiceName.Equals(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

This is not the best option if you have several records that you don't need to get accross the network.

Another option is to create a Data Service Operation.

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<Service> GetServicesByServiceName(string serviceNames)
{
    var serviceNamesArray = serviceNames.Split(',');
    var ctx = YourContext();
    return ctx.Services.Include("ServiceQueryExpansion").Where(s => serviceNamesArrays.Any(n => s.ServiceName.Equals(n, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))).AsQueryable();
}
```